# Use the search API to query Stack Overflow Teams questions

Tags: support, search, api, stack-overflow-for-teams

We have Stack Overflow for Teams at my company. Is it possible to use the [search API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) to query questions there?

Comment: I think that's better asked at Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. There is a [documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams) specifically for this subject. Only read-only access is provided, but fortunately searching *is* read-only.

Most of the API support is provided at [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/), not here. There is a [stack-overflow-for-teams tag](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-for-teams). One of the common pitfalls is not using the right team parameter value (they should start with `stackoverflow.com/c/`), as mentioned [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/8202/unable-to-make-api-calls-using-access-token-for-private-stack-overflow-teams-sit#comment17124_8203).